# How to take hourly backups on Azure

Tags: azure

I want to take hourly backups on azure, All I can see is that we can take 12H or 24H backups, Is there a way azure can take hourly backups daily?

Thanks.

Comment: AFAIK currently Azure does not support hourly backups, but you can Use Azure Logic app to automate the process of taking hourly backups.

Comment: It would be great if you provide more details like what you have tried to provide detail solution.

Comment: @vijaya I have configured my database on azure to take backups every 12 hours. But my business need to take backup every 1 hour but all I can see are 12H or 24H backups in configure policies, I need a way to take backups on hourly bases. How can i do this using azure logic app?

Comment: Based on your earlier requirement i tried to provide solution but i just saw your comment i will edit my answer according to your requirement. Azure SQL Database has built-in capabilities for automated backups it does not support taking hourly backups, but you can perform this by logic Apps by taking recurrence trigger and instead of azure blob use azure sql data base action.

Answer (score 1):

By following this [MS document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-managed-disks) you can create Backup vault ana backup policy.

- In create backup policy you can choose **Datasource type** as **Azure Disks, Azure Blobs or Azure Database** as shown in below image.
  [image]
- If you take **Azure Disks** as DataSource type in **Schedule + retention** **you can Specify time when the backup will happen in Hourly or Daily in Backup frequency** as shown below.
  [image]

*But For Azure Blobs and Azure Database the Backup Schedule frequency is Daily or Weekly.
[image]
[image]

- If you want your azure storage account to be hourly backup **AFAIK you can do it by using logic Apps Recurrence trigger** and Azure blob storage actions as shown in below workflow.
  [image]

**In Recurrence trigger You can backup it in hourly by taking Frequency Hour and In Interval you can take every 1or2.... hrs.
Here It backups every 1hour .**
[image]

Then you can use list blobs action and point it to the folder you want to backup.
[image]

Then **in For each** you can retrieve previous action content then you can use Get blob content using path action and **Create blob action** . In  "Copy Blob" action, specify the name of the storage container where you want to store the backup, and provide a unique name for the backup file
[image]

In this way you can mention hourly backup in Recurrence in Trigger.

*Azure SQL Database has built-in capabilities for automated backups it does not support taking hourly backups.

- **If in case your requirement is Azure SQL Database The same above process you can follow by taking Recurrence trigger in hourly bases and then instead of Azure blob storage use Azure SQL Database action and Add Azure SQL Database - Export Database" action**.

Reference [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/database-export?view=azuresql)

Comment: use Azure SQL Database action and Add Azure SQL Database - Export Database" action**. This action will export the database to a .bacpac file, which can be imported later to restore the database. In order to automate the process, you will need to use the Azure SQL Database Export Data-tier Application (DACPAC) to export a .bacpac file which contains the database schema and data. The .bacpac file can then be imported back to the Azure SQL Database to restore the database.
Reference [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/database-export?view=azuresql)